# Why is an S3 object without public permissions accessible through http.get() in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an [S3 object](http://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudfront.s3post.cf/posts.json.gz) that is publicly not available. If you click on that link, you should get the `<code>Access Denied</code>` error.

However, if I run the following script on a Node server locally on my Mac, I'm able to download the file -

```
var s3file = fs.createWriteStream("s3posts.json.gz");
http.get("http://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudfront.s3post.cf/posts.json.gz", function(response) {
    response.pipe(s3file);
});
```

I went through all of my bucket and object configuration; there's nothing allowing the object to be accessed publicly.

If AWS's policies are by private by default and I haven't explicitly given any permissions, why is the object available for download while not being available on the browser?

What can I do to prevent the object from being downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen what actually gets downloaded by that script?

When I run your Node example on my machine, here is the contents of s3posts.json.gz:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>946B9510D519E44B</RequestId>
<HostId>eMlB8tG95Ur5fjIHo/NxfI6Ucjs/b4vcMNKYiZPZk94Db6BgrekTRVoaJTccxmQqN1eb91O673A=</HostId>
</Error>
```

It seems that everything is fine, unless that is indeed the real contents of that file that you want to protect.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I found a whole new issue with downloading zipped JSON S3 files and unzipping them but this helps me to start troubleshooting the issue.